# “Ought-is misstatements”

Tags: adjectives

The Ought-is fallacy is when one assumes that what he/she wishes for is true.

Is it correct to use ‘ought-is’ as an adjective and say the following sentence: they do not know their handbook, except ought-is misstatements.

Is this correct, or does it sound wrong? I considered using other fallacy names like straw man or ad-hoc, and it sounded acceptable to me.

Comment: There are plenty of Google hits for "is-ought fallacy" and variations. Are you wondering how to punctuate, or whether is goes before ought, or something else?

Comment: In the States, I've only heard of *wishful thinking*.

Comment: Not every fallacy has a name, despite the best efforts of the Fallacy Trust.

Comment: @StuartF They seem to be wondering whether they can use the term as a modifier for "misstatements". I.e. use "ought-is misstatements" as short for "misstatements based on the ought-is fallacy".

Comment: Phrases are always clearer than noun compounds. Every time something is deleted, information is lost.

Comment: "except" seems wrong as well. Misstatements are an example of them not knowing the handbook, not exceptions.

Comment: @Barmar yes I was considering the use as a modifier… Also the ‘ought-is misstatements’  are assumed to be part of the handbook. Therefore we can make them an exception. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that the misstatements were on the part of the users, not the authors of the handbook.

Comment: The consensus so far seems to be that the usage is incomprehensible, even if not wrong, except in a context that is not given explicitly by the question. Because the discussion has informed the questioner, despite his slight lack of clarity, it seems pointless to get more discussion. I this vote to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as explained in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's OK grammatically. English is very flexible in what you can use as a modifier in this fashion.

However, "ought-is" is not a well known term (at least in the US) outside logicians who study fallacies, so the reference may not be understood by most people. As @Yosef Bankin mentioned in a comment, the more common term is "wishful thinking". So you might want to write

> They do not know their handbook, except for its wishful thinking misstatements.

Comment: *Ought-is* is not an established term anywhere. There is a well established philosophical term *is-ought fallacy*, which means something different from what the OP has in mind. Anybody who may have used the term *ought-is fallacy* was presupposing that the audience was familiar with the literature about the is-ought fallacy, and will recognise in the use of the new term an allusion to the more familiar one. If one is not writing for such an audience, one should avoid the term.

Comment: @jsw29 Since I'm not an expert on fallacies, I took the OP at their word when describing the ought-is fallacy.

Answer (score -1):

The relationship between 'is' and 'ought' appears in philosophical discussions.  Originally, the philosopher David Hume, in his treatise *On Human Nature*, raised what is often referred to as the 'ought/is' question.

It is often expressed as:

> 'ought' does not imply 'is'.

This is a striking way of expressing what amounts to the proposition that statements of value are not statements of fact, also known as the 'fact/value' issue.

There is an obvious example of this in the use of the verb 'ought' in a statement like

> I ought to be with you by three this afternoon.

That is not a definite **promise** but an **estimate**.  If I don't arrive by that time, I have not misled you and I have not made a mistake.

It was the moral use of *ought* that David Hume was discussing, and he was raising a divisive question.  The idea that matters of morality are not matters of fact ('surely torturing children - or anyone - just **is** wrong. If it were just a matter of opinion the way is open to mayhem').  On the other hand there are values that are held by some communities that others reject.  Jains believe that no living creatures ought to be killed for any reason.  If we say that 'ought' statements are factual and we eat meat, then we have to concede that either Jains are making a mistake of fact and are wasting their time or that we are making a (factual) mistake and doing wrong.

I suggest that if you wish to take this further, it is a philosophical question that should be moved to the 'philosophy' group.

I do not think this matter can be said to be settled even today.  It raises a host of questions:  whether the basis of morality/values is that it/they has/have being given by God, whether their validity is not divine but a human claim  about what creates the greatest happiness/well-being or least pain/suffering for the greatest number of people (Utilitarianism) or what enables societies to function or ... and so on.